# How to fix DeleteManyAsync returning 0 records deleted with Filter?

Tags: c#, mongodb, filter, ienumerable, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a delete method that takes in an IEnumerable of Ids that are of type string, and have a filter taking in those ids using Filter.In. However when passing in a set of ids I am getting a count of 0 for records deleted. Is my filter causing the issue?

I've created a test method to test my delete method and am passing in ids to try and have them deleted.

---

**Test Solution**

MongodDB Test method for delete method

```
    [Theory]
    [InlineData(1)]
    [InlineData(100)]
    public async void TEST_DELETE(int quantity)
    {
        using (var server = StartServer())
        {
            // Arrange
            var collection = SetupCollection(server.Database, quantity);
            var dataUtility = new MongoDataUtility(server.Database, 
    MongoDbSettings);
            var service = new MongoDatabaseService(dataUtility, Logger);

            var items = 
    collection.FindSync(FilterDefinition<BsonDocument>.Empty)
    .ToIdCollection();
            _output.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(items, 
    Formatting.Indented));

            // Act
            var result = await 
    dataUtility.DeleteIdentifiedDataAsync(items, CollectionName);
            _output.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result, 
    Formatting.Indented));

            // Assert
            Assert.True(result.DeletedCount.Equals(items.Count));
        }
    }
```

Setup collection

```
    public IMongoCollection<BsonDocument> SetupCollection(IMongoDatabase db, 
    int quantity)
    {
        var collection = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(CollectionName);

        AddCreateDateIndex(collection);
        SeedData(collection, quantity);

        return collection;
    }
```

Seed data

```
    public void SeedData(IMongoCollection<BsonDocument> collection, int? 
    quantity = null)
    {
        if (quantity != null && quantity > 0)
        {
            collection.InsertMany(GenerateTestData((int)quantity));
        }
    }
```

---

**Project**

MongoDB delete method

```
 public async Task<DeleteResult> 
 DeleteIdentifiedDataAsync(IEnumerable<ObjectId> ids, string Resource, 
 CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        var collection = _db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(Resource);
        var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.In("_id", ids);

        if (ids != null && ids.Any() )
        {
            return await collection.DeleteManyAsync(filter, 
 cancellationToken);
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Extensions

```
    public static ICollection<ObjectId> ToIdCollection(this 
    IAsyncCursor<BsonDocument> @this)
    {
        return @this.Find(Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Empty)
            .ToEnumerable()
            .Select(s => s["_id"].AsObjectId)
            .ToList();
    }
```

Comment: Could you also show `ToIdCollection` and `SetupCollection` ? Are you sure that query and delete is running on the same database / collection ?

Comment: @mickl I added the methods associated with the delete method, and yes they are running on the same database / collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ToIdCollection` method gets all the `ids` but also converts them from `ObjectId` to `String` when you run `.Select(dict => dict["_id"].ToString())`. MongoDB compares both values and types when you run `DeleteManyAsync` and that's why there is no match - you're trying to compare list of strings against ObjectIds that are stored in the database.

To fix that you can replace `ToIdCollection` with following implementation:

```
return @this.Find(Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Empty)
                        .ToEnumerable()
                        .Select(s => s["_id"].AsObjectId)
                        .ToList()
```

Comment: With that implementation i'm getting
      Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
     Error CS1929 'IAsyncCursor<BsonDocument>' does not contain a definition for 
     'Find' and the best extension method overload 
     'IMongoCollectionExtensions.Find<BsonDocument> 
    (IMongoCollection<BsonDocument>, FilterDefinition<BsonDocument>, FindOptions)' 
    requires a receiver of type 'IMongoCollection<BsonDocument>'  
    AHP.DataRetention.Agent C:\Code\Git\ah-platform-dataretention- 
    agent\src\AHP.DataRetention.Agent\Extensions\MongoExtensions.cs 47 Active

Comment: @Danny you need to change `IEnumerable<string>` to `IEnumerable<ObjectId>` in few places. I've tested that `var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.In("_id", ids);
            var res = Col.DeleteMany(filter);` passing a list of `ObjectId` and it works

Comment: I made the changes and edited, also clarified what is in the test solution and what is in the project. I think my main issue is that IAsyncCursor does not have the find method.

Comment: @Danny I think you don't need this part `collection.FindSync(FilterDefinition<BsonDocument>.Empty)`, can't you run `Find` in `ToIdCollection` directly on `MongoCollection` ? That should solve the  issue